# Swift3(Xcode9.0)でのジオフェンシング処理の実行時に領域判定されない

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, gps

現在iOSアプリの製作を行なっています。
Xcode9.0,Swift3を用いて、複数地点の領域判定（ジオフェンシング）を行おうと試みているのですが、時にアプリ実行時に領域判定をしない地点が存在します。
（実行のタイミングによって領域検知をしたりしなかったりが変化します）

原因/解決策についてお詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、どうぞご回答宜しくお願いいたします。

```
func startMonitoring() {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    let tokyo = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.702141, 139.775123)
    self.monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: tokyo, radius: 100, identifier: "Tokyo")

    let newyork = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.759188, -73.984659)
    self.monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: newyork, radius: 100, identifier: "newyork")

    let london = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.510058, -0.134471)
    self.monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: london, radius: 100, identifier: "London")

    self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: self.monitoredRegion)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print(region.identifier + "に入りました！")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print(region.identifier + "から出ました！")
}
```

Comment: 実行時に初めから領域内にいるとうまく検知できないことがあるようです。

Comment: @小川航佑さん ご回答ありがとうございます。領域外からの開始も試みてみたのですが、残念ながら解決致しませんでした。